# Stata's estout with two sets of margins

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a model like this:

```
webuse nlswork
poisson hours i.union##c.tenure, robust
margins union, dydx(tenure)
margins rb1.union, dydx(tenure)
```

I would like to stack the two AMEs on top of the differences of the AMEs using Ben Jann's -estout-. Unfortunately, you need to post the margins results for estout, which interferes with the second margins command.

Is there any way around this?

Cross-posted at the [Statalist forum](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/572317-estout-with-two-sets-of-margins) for some time without an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used -estout-, but perhaps this will give you a start.

```
 webuse nlswork
 poisson hours i.union##c.tenure, robust
 estimates store m0
 
 margins union, dydx(tenure) post
 estimates store m1

 estimates restore m0

 margins rb1.union, dydx(tenure) post
 estimates store m2
```

Why this works: `margins` needs access to the results of the original command, `poisson` in this example. As `margins` does not itself leave estimation results behind, the original results remain available if you run `margins` without `post`, and you can have several `margins` commands in a row without problems.  However, if you add the `post` option to the first `margins` command, the new posted results displace those in memory. In that case, the second `margins` will complain that

> margins cannot work with its own posted results

The solution, therefore, is to present the second `margins` with the original estimation results, just what `estimates restore` is designed to do.

### Update

`r(table)` contains all the results from `margins`, and the columns are named. Here's a version of Roberto's stacking solution that takes advantage of these properties:

```
use nlswork, clear,
poisson hours i.union##c.tenure, robust

margins union, dydx(tenure)
matrix list r(table)
matrix m1 = r(table)
matrix  m11 = m1["b".."se", 1...]'
matrix m12 = m1["ll".."ul",1...]'
matrix first = m11,m12

margins rb1.union, dydx(tenure)
matrix m2 = r(table)
matrix m21 = m2["b".."se", 1...]'
matrix m22 = m2["ll".."ul",1...]'
matrix second = m21,m22
matrix rownames second = tenure:diff

matrix RESULTS = first \ second
estout matrix(RESULTS)
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution.

Comment: I would like to stack first on top of the second in one column. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: They can be stacked, with some additional work. I provided an update to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

`estout` takes matrices, so maybe you can try with that:

```
webuse nlswork, clear

poisson hours i.union##c.tenure, robust
margins union, dydx(tenure)

matrix first = r(b)
matrix list first

margins rb1.union, dydx(tenure)

matrix second = r(b)
matrix list second

*-----

matrix b = first[1,1] ,  first[1,2] \ second[1,1] ,  .

estout matrix(b)
```

You would need to polish the results, of course.

### Update

There's a [thread on Statalist from 2007](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2007-06/msg00636.html), where Ben Jann (the author of `estout`) clarifies that stacking multiple *stored results* into one column is not possible with `estout` alone. His solution involves a `program` that merges results manipulating matrices and column/row names.

For the example you have provided, something like the following works:

```
webuse nlswork, clear

poisson hours i.union##c.tenure, robust

// first margin
margins union, dydx(tenure)
matrix first = r(b)

// second margin
margins rb1.union, dydx(tenure)
matrix second = r(b)
matrix rownames second = tenure:diff

// put together
matrix c = first' \ second

estout matrix(c)
```

(The thread is a bit old so I'm not sure if `estout` has been updated to do this at present.)

Comment: Very nice, Roberto! I "polish" this solution in the update to my own answer.  I extract from `r(table)` instead of `e(b)` and `e(V)` as Ben did; this not only gets more statistics but also simplifies the names problem somewhat.